# Induction proof question

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Show by induction that for all integers n $\ge$ 1 $$ \sum_{i=1}^n i3^i = \frac{3(2n3^n-3^n+1)}{4} $$

Starting with n = 1 will give me LHS = 3 and RHS = 3.

Inserting n = p gives $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^p i3^i = \frac{3(2p3^p-3^p+1)}{4} $$

Going to n = p+1 gives me LHS  $$\frac{3(2p3^p-3^p+1)}{4} +(p+1)3^{p+1}$$

I tried to expand the RHS for $$\frac{3(2(p+1)3^{p+1}-3^{p+1}+1)}{4}$$ so it becomes $$\frac{3(2p+2)3^{p+1}-3^{p+1}+1)}{4}$$ then
$$\frac{3(p(2+2)3^{p+1}-3^{p+1}+1)}{4}$$ until 
$$\frac{3(p(2+2)3*3^{p}-3*3^{p}+1)}{4}$$

Is this the right way to expand this formula?

Comment: Check and correct occurrences of $i,n,p$.  In particular, the claim seems to have a mismatch of variables.

Comment: Edited the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be numerous typos, either in terms of missing parentheses, or mismatched variables in your solution.

In particular, the claim is written as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i3^i=\frac{3(2i3^i-3i+1)}{4}$.  Surely, you mean to have $n$'s on the RHS instead of $i$'s.

The line that begins "inserting $n=p$ gives", shouldn't that be $\sum\limits_{i=1}^p i3^i = \frac{3(2p3^p-3p+1)}{4}$.  Why do you write $p3^p$?

After the phrase "so it becomes"  you have $\frac{3(2p+2)3^{p+1}-3^{p+1}+1)}{4}$ which has a total of one left parenthesis and two right parenthesis.  Surely, you meant to say $\frac{3\color{red}{(}(2p+2)3^{p+1}-3^{p+1}+1)}{4}$

The next line which begins "then" you have $\frac{3(p(2+2)3^{p+1}-3^{p+1}+1)}{4}$.  How did that step go?  $(2p+2)\neq p(2+2)$ in general (only for the one case when $p=1$)

You have made a good start, but there is still more manipulation to do before you finally get the LHS to appear equal the RHS.  It is usually easier to put things into a fraction than take things out of a fraction, so I would suggest continuing to work on the LHS a bit more.

For information on how to format an induction proof, I recommend viewing [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1255268/179297).

---

For the beginnings of a better worded proof:

**Claim:** $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni3^i = \frac{3(2n3^n-3n+1)}{4}$ for all $n\geq 1$

**Proof:** The claim holds for $n=1$.

Let us assume for our induction hypothesis that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^pi3^i = \frac{3(2p3^p-3p+1)}{4}$ for some $p\geq 1$.  Then for $p+1$ we have:

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p+1}i3^i &= (p+1)3^{p+1}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^p i3^i\\
&=(p+1)3^{p+1}+\frac{3(2p3^p-3p+1)}{4}&\text{by induction hypothesis}\\
&=\frac{4p3^{p+1}+4\cdot 3^{p+1}}{4}+\frac{3(2p3^p-3p+1)}{4}\\
&=\frac{4p3^{p+1}+4\cdot 3^{p+1} + 2p3^{p+1}-9p+3}{4}\\
&=\frac{6p3^{p+1}+4\cdot 3^{p+1} - 9p+3}{4}\\
&\vdots
\end{array}$$

Comment: Yes i have edited so it is N on the RHS and changed insertining n = p as you suggested.

$$\frac{3(p(2+2)3^{p+1}-3^{p+1}+1)}{4} $$ was a guess from me since i couldnt figure out where to go.

Comment: @addde added the beginnings of a proof.  Remember that you can always *multiply by one* and it won't change anything and you can always *add zero* and it won't change anything.  The trick sometimes is what "one" and "zero" you use.  (By "adding zero" that could mean adding and subtracting the same thing, like adding $(2p+1-2p-1)$).  It also helps sometimes to break pieces apart into multiple smaller pieces, like $4\cdot 3^{p+1}=2\cdot 3^{p+1} + 2\cdot 3^{p+1}$ etc

Comment: RHS should be $$\sum_{i=1}^n i3^i = \frac{3(2n3^n-3^n+1)}{4}$$ though.

Comment: Which is why I put dots.  I didn't finish the proof.  There's only one or two steps left to complete it though.