# Proving $( A - B ) - C = A - ( B ∪ C )$ using set identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a list of set identities that I need to apply to prove the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side. I am stuck on which rules to use.

> For all sets $A,B,C$,  show that
>          $$( A - B ) - C = A - ( B ∪ C ).$$

I found this [document of set identities](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/smmg/archive/2012/Moore/Sets_Laws.pdf) and I see that $A - B$ is equal to $A \cap B^C$, but then I get stuck. I also do not know if I am going in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very easy way to prove your identity using basic set algebra:
\begin{align}
(A-B)-C&\equiv (A\cap B^C)\cap C^C\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&\equiv A\cap(B^C\cap C^C)\tag{by assoc. of $\cap$}\\[0.5em]
&\equiv A\cap(B\cup C)^C\tag{DeMorgan}\\[0.5em]
&\equiv A-(B\cup C)\tag{by definition}
\end{align}
Did all of that make sense? Feel free to comment if a step was unclear.

Comment: This was the clearest solution, although I did understand the other answers. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you found it helpful--I find that writing notes in the margin is always a good idea to force you to make sure you know how each step works (such as how associativity comes into play, etc.).

Comment: I think I will do that actually! I just tried the next problem set and it was super easy after using your answer as a guide on how to process the problem. :]

Comment: Excellent! I would recommend the practice of making margin notes/comments regardless of whether or not you're proving a set identity. If you are taking a discrete class, then you will no doubt come across induction. When you do induction proofs, actually writing the proof gets to be a little tricky. The same practice is very helpful (see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof/1255268#1255268) for an example). As always, provide clarity whenever possible! Margin notes seem to do just that (i.e., provide clarity).

Answer (score 5):

$$x \in (A-B)-C \Leftrightarrow x \in A-B \wedge x \notin C \Leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge x \notin B \wedge x \notin C \Leftrightarrow x \in A-(B \cup C)$$

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you!

Comment: @NilsR You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have $(A - B) = A\cap B^{c}$. Apply this to the right hand side of the equality you need to prove to obtain
$$
A-(B\cup C) = A\cap(B\cup C)^{c}.
$$
By De Morgan's Law, $(B\cup C)^{c} = B^{c}\cap C^{c}$. Therefore
$$
A - (B\cup C) = A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c} = (A-B)-C.
$$