# Use the PMI to prove the following $4^{k}-1$ is divisible by 3.

Tags: induction

> $4^{n}-1$ is divisible by $3.$

(i) Basis Step: $P(1)$is true because $4^1 -1=3 $ and $3\mid3$.

(ii) Suppose $P(k)$ is true for induction hypothesis $3\mid4^{k}-1$.

Show $(k+1)$ is true $3\mid4^{k+1}$

Now here is where things gets tricky.

$\Rightarrow 4^{k+1} -1 = \left(4^{k}*4 \right)-1 =$

I cannot seem to figure out how one factors this any further. I just cannot seem to make it divisible by 3. Could someone show me how to do this?

Comment: Use `\mid` instead of the simple `|` when talking about divisibility. Also, you should specify what your proposition $P(n)$ is. You reference $P(1)$ but never say what $P$ actually is. Also, don't you mean to show that $P(k+1)$ is true due to the assumption that $P(k)$ is true? Not just $(k+1)$ [whatever that might mean].

Comment: In the future, I would strongly recommend that you use [this template](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof/1255268#1255268) for writing your induction proofs. Much of it may seem somewhat pointless, but it *forces* you to write everything out and understand what you are doing. After you have written a number of different induction proofs, then you can relax your expository style, but I imagine it would be helpful at this point for you to flesh everything out as much as possible.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I will make the template my new desktop wallpaper. If it pleases you.

Comment: do you know modular arithmetic instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\geq1$, let $S(n)$ denote the statement
$$
S(n) : 3\mid(4^n-1)\Longleftrightarrow4^n-1=3m, m\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
**Base case ($n=1$):** $S(1)$ says that $3\mid(4^1-1)$, and this is true.

**Inductive step:** Fix some $k\geq1$, and assume that $S(k)$ is true where
$$
S(k) : 3\mid(4^k-1)\Longleftrightarrow4^k-1=3\ell, \ell\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
To be proved is that $S(k+1)$ follows where
$$
S(k+1) : 3\mid(4^{k+1}-1)\Longleftrightarrow4^{k+1}-1=3\eta, \eta\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Beginning with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
4^{k+1}-1&= 4(4^k-1)+3\tag{rearrange}\\[1em]
&= 4\cdot3 \ell+3\tag{by $S(k)$}\\[1em]
&= 3(4\ell+1)\tag{factor out 3}\\[1em]
&= 3\eta,\tag{$\eta=4\ell+1, \eta\in\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

Thus, by mathematical induction, the statement $S(n)$ is true for all $n\geq1$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: If you are wondering where the $m$ and $\ell$ come from and what they are, ask yourself what it means for something to be divisible by 3.

Comment: I thought there was a difference between divide $|$ and divisible \

Comment: Maybe they were always the same thing I just never thought too deep into it.

Comment: Saying an integer $\eta$ is divisible by $7$, for instance, means that $\eta$ is a multiple of $7$. And you can write this as follows: $\eta=7\ell$, where $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$. You could also write $7\mid\eta$, which means "$7$ divides $\eta$." Does that clear things up at all?

Comment: Yes now I see the difference. I am still thinking about the m and L though.

Comment: See the revised proof--it should be *much* clearer now.

Comment: One last question. Is it right to assume. $4^{k+1}-1=-3.$

Comment: That is what I think @ZackNi is saying.

Comment: How could you assume that? Is there anything about my proof that is unclear? If not, then I think you should be on the right track. If so, then please indicate where.

Comment: I just thinking where else could the 3 come from. It has to be from the other side. Very thorough proof by the by.

Comment: $4^{k+1}-1= 4(4^k-1)+3=4\cdot4^k-4\cdot1+3=4^{k+1}-1$ ... you are simply rewriting the expression *so that you can use the inductive hypothesis*.

Answer (score 3):

Inductive assumption: $3 \mid (4^k-1)$, and therefore $(4^k-1) = 3m$ for some $m$.

$4(4^k-1) = 4^{k+1} -4 = 4^{k+1}-3-1$

so $4^{k+1}-1= 4(4^k-1)+3 = 12m+3$ which is divisible by $3$, completing the induction.

Comment: I see what you did you took and distributed the 4 so that you got $4^{k+1}-4$

Comment: Where did the $m$ come from?

Comment: From assumption

Comment: How did the -3 go from negative to + 3?

Comment: also is $4^{k}-1 = 3m?$

Comment: think for example 3=3, move 3 to right 0 = 3-3. that's why -3 go from negative to +3

Comment: $4^k-1 =3m$ because of induction assumption

Comment: Yes. $4^{k}-1 = 3m$.

Comment: @ZackNi - Edited that in to your answer. What is the relevance of the gcd remark?

Comment: Sorry i misapprehended the notion of gcd. I will delete it.

Answer (score 1):

$$4^{k+1}-1=4\cdot 4^k-1=4\cdot (4^k-1+1)-1=4(4^k-1)+4(4)-1=4(4^k-1)+15.$$ So $3|(4^k-1)\implies 3|(4^{k+1}-1).$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(n)$ be the statement: $4^{n}-1$ is divisible by $3$

Basis step: $S(1)$: $\hspace{5 mm}4^{(1)}-1=3$, which is divisible by $3$

Inductive step:

Assume $S(k)$ is true, i.e. assume that $4^{k}-1$ is divisible by $3$

$\hspace{59 mm}\Rightarrow 4^{k}-1=3A$; $A\in\mathbb{N}$

$\hspace{59 mm}\Rightarrow 4^{k}=3A+1$

$S(k+1)$: $4^{k+1}-1$

$\hspace{12.5 mm}=4\bullet{4^{k}}-1$

$\hspace{12.5 mm}=4\hspace{1 mm}(3A+1)-1$

$\hspace{12.5 mm}=12A+4-1$

$\hspace{12.5 mm}=12A+3$

$\hspace{12.5 mm}=3\hspace{1 mm}(4A+1)$, which is divisible by $3$

So, $S(k+1)$ is true whenever $S(k)$ is true.

Therefore, $4^{n}-1$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Would this be the same answer as @Daniel W.Farlow?

Comment: The result is the same, but the methods are slightly different. I directly substituted $3A+1$ in place of $4^{k}$ in the $S(k+1)$ step.

Answer (score -2):

Rewrite statement (*) as $(3+1)^n =3k+1.$ When $n=1$ let $k=1.$

Assume $(3+1)^n =3k+1 $. $(3+1)(3k+1)=3(3k+1)+3k+1=3(3k+1+k)+1 .$

Comment: I hope you realize that it is frowned upon to add *multiple* answers when one will suffice (unless the answers are wholly different and both quite lengthy, usually you can lump more than answer together in a single post--there is no need for this).

Comment: Also, it is high time for you to learn some [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please use this in the future when asking or answering questions. I believe you would find everyone on MSE to be more receptive. `:-)`

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I don't want them to be receptive. I want them to think about what I wrote.