# Proving that $4k < 2^k$ by induction

Tags: inequality, induction

> Prove that $4k < 2^k$ by induction.

It holds for $k = 5$. Assume $ k = n + 1 $. Then

$4(n+1) < 2^{(n+1)}$

$4n + 4 < 2^n * 2$

$2n + 2 \leq 2^n$

Now I just need to show that

$2n + 2 \leq 4n$

$n + 1 \leq 2n$

$1 \leq n$

And because I chose $n = 5$ which is greater than $1$, this should prove that the formula holds for $n \geq 5$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Could not relate one step with another.

Comment: MathsProTip: Instead of proving this holds for n=5, prove it holds for k.

Comment: your presentation is not clear try to mimic more formal proof format.

Comment: On a different note, you may find [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof) helpful on how to write a clear induction proof (I imagine it would help you structure your argument(s) more effectively, force you to know what you are doing, etc.).

Comment: @hxd1011 What does "more formal proof format" even mean?

Comment: First you show that it is true for some $n$, in this case $5$. Then you show if it is true for $n$ it must logically follow that it is true for $n+1$. So you begin with the fact that it is true for $n=5$. Then you show that if for any particular $n$, $4n<2^n$ it must logically follow that $4(n+1)<2^{n+1}$. So you would probably do something like $4(n+1)=4n+4<2^n+4=2^n+2^2$ etc and try to arrive at $2^{n+1}$ on the right.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow something like this http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/lamport-how-to-write.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made lots of little mistakes but your biggest mistake is that you inductions step, doesn't actually do any inducing.

A proper induction step always goes like this:

=======

We assume that something is true for a specific $k = n$

$\implies$

Then something is true for $k = n+1$.

======

Thus, we start with showing it is true for $k= $ base case; thus we can conclude it is true of $k = $ base case $ + 1$; thus we can conclude it is true for $k = $ base case $ + 2$; thus we con conclude it is true for $k = $ base case $ + 3$; the we can....

... and so on.  We can conclude it is true for all possible numbers $k$.

But your induction step didn't try to conclude something for $k = n + 1$ from something for $k = n$.

Instead you tried to assume something was true for $k = n+1$ and then show if it's true for $k = n + 1 $ then $n \ge 1$ and therefor it must be true for all numbers.

This is wrong.  1) your logic is backwards.  You can't start at a conclusion and get a basic result and assume your conclusion is true.  That just isn't logical. But more importantly 2) your induction doesn't build forward step by step.  You didn't do *anything* to do with the statement being true for $k = n$.

THat's your big mistake.  Your small mistakes are:

a) In stating that you are trying to prove $4k < 2^k$ you didn't state the *essential* condition that $k \ge 5$.  This just isn't true if $k = 1,2,3,4$.

b)Your logic can't start with a conclusion, get the result $n \ge 1$ and assume you conclusion is true.

Consider this:  Assume $25 > 36$.  Then as $47 > 25$ I get $47 > 25>  36$ so $47 > 36$.  So $11 > 0$.  So $1 > 0$.  That is a true statement so $25 > 36$.

I hope you see why that is bull#*@%.

c)  You claimed $2n+2 \le 2^n$ when you meant $2n+2 < 2^n$.

d) You claimed "all we need to show is $2n + 2 \le 4n$".  That isn't true.  If $2n+ 2 \le 4n$ and $2n+2 \le 2^n$ we can not conclude anything about how $4n$ relates to $2^n$.  Maybe $4n < 2^n$ maybe $4n > 2^n$ or maybe $4n = 2^n$.

To reach that conclusion you have to show that $4n \le 2n + 2$ and therefore as $2n+2 < 2^n$ we can conclude by transitivity that $4n < 2^n$.

But we can't prove $4n \le 2n+2$ ... because it isn't. Or proof was flawed from the beginning because the logic of mistake b) doesn't work.

So let's fix this:

=====

Prove $4k < 2^k$ for all $k \ge 5$.

Well it is true for $k = 5$ as $4*5 = 20 < 32 = 2^5$.

Induction step:

We assume it is true for some $k = n$.  (This is okay because we know it is true for $k = n = 5$.)

So $4n < 2^n$

We need to find steps

$\implies.....$

$\implies.....$

$\implies.....$ $4(n+1) < 2^{n+1}$.

Can we do that?

Well,

$4n < 2^n$

$4n + 4 < 2^n + 4$

$4n + 4 < 2^n + 4 \le 2^n + 4n$ (because $n \ge 1$ so $4n \ge 4$)

$4n + 4 < 2^n + 4n < 2^n + 2^n$.

$4(n+1) < 2*2^n = 2^{n+1}$

and we have proven the induction step.

Thus we can conclude as it is true for $k = 5$, it is true for $k = 6$.  And as it is true for $k = 6$ it is true for $k = 7$, and so on.  By *induction* we have shown it is true for *all* $k \ge 5$.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot, but I have one question. Couldn't you have skipped this step $4n+4 < 2^n + 4 ≤ 2^n + 4n$ by showing $4n+4 < 2^n + 4 < 2^n + 2^n$ directly? Also didn't you also need to show that for that to be true, you also need to show that $2^n > 4$ for $ n > 2 $?

Comment: There's several ways to do it.   My first thought was that 4(n+1) = 4n + 4 < 2^n +4 <+ 2^n + 2^n but that'd require showing 2^n > 4 for n >= 2.  Which is why I prefer 4n + 4 <= 4n + 4n (because n >= 1 which is true for all N so it assumes nothing).  Another way would be $2^{n+1} = 2*2^n > 2*4n = 4n + 4n >= 4n +4 = 4(n+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following (see if you can determine how one step relates to another): 
\begin{align}
4(k+1)&=4k+4\\[1em]
&< 2^k+4\tag{why?}\\[1em]
&< 2^k+2^k\tag{why?}\\[1em]
&= 2\cdot2^k\\[1em]
&=2^{k+1}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

You got the basis step correct by checking that $4n<2^n$ for $n=5$.

Next, you must prove that $4N<2^N \implies 4(N+1) < 2^{N+1}$ for $N\geq5$

When trying to solve this problem, simplify the right-hand-side of this implication to a form that is easily comparable to the left-hand-side.

Notice that $4(N+1) < 2^{N+1}$ holds if and only if

$4N+4 < 2^N *2$

Then you might notice that the inductive hypothesis gives us that

$4N+4 < 2^N + 4$ (since we are assuming $4N < 2^N$).

These two formulae look similar, so we are almost done.

Now we need only show that $2^N + 4 < 2^N * 2 $

Notice $2^N * 2 = 2^N + 2^N $.

Can you now show that $2^N + 4 < 2^N + 2^N$ for $N \geq 5$?

Do that, and you're done! Hooray for you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ Equivalently we seek to prove that $\,f(n) = 2^n/(4n) > 1\,$ for all $\,n\ge 5.$

Note $\,f(5)>1\,$ and $\,f(n\!+\!1)/f(n) = 2n/(n\!+\!1) \ge 1\,$ for $\,n\ge 5\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{f(n\!+\!1) \ge f(n)}\,$

Hence the induction reduces to a trivial one: $ $ an $\rm\color{#c00}{increasing}$ sequence stays $\,\ge\, $ its initial value. From this view, the induction step becomes obvious, boiling down to transitivity of $\,\ge,\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{align} f(n)\ge f(5)\,&\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{f(n\!+\!1)\ge f(n)} \ge f(5)\\[0.3em]
{\rm i.e.}\quad P(n)\,&\Rightarrow\,P(n\!+\!1)\end{align}$$

**Remark** $ $ This is not an ad-hoc trick. Rather, it is a special case of a general method of transforming such problems into a simpler form where the inductive step is more obvious. It is a special case of [multiplicative telescopy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy+multiplicative) Follow the link for many further examples.

Note that once you prove by induction that result about increasing sequences, you can invoke the result as a Lemma for other induction problems of this type (which are quite common, as you can see from the links).

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of $n$ should only be for the basis of the induction, not for the inductive step.

What you need to do is to show that if $4n<2^n$ then $4(n+1)<2^{n+1}$. One way of doing that is to say that $4(n+1)=4n+4<2^n+4$ and then argue that $x+4<2x$ for the relevant values.