# Prove $2^n \lt\ n!$

Tags: induction, factorial

> Prove by induction: $A(n) = 2^n \lt\ n!$

$A(n+1) = 2^{n+1} \lt\ (n+1)!$

The expression below is true for $n = 5$.

$2^n \lt\ \frac{n!}{2}$

Then, we have:

$2^n \lt\ \frac{n!}{2} \lt\ n! \lt\ (n+1)!$

Which implies that:

$2^{n+1}  \lt\ (n+1)!$          for every $n \ge\ 5$

Is this proof correct?

**Update:** the case is true for $n = 4$. It's true for $n = 5$, too. I started the induction proof with $n = 5$.

Let be more clear:

$A(n) = 2^n \lt\ n!$ is true for $n = 5$.

For $n= 5$, the expression $2^n \lt\ \frac{n!}{2}$ is true too.

From the expression above, we can deduce:
$$2^n \lt\ \frac{n!}{2} \lt\ n! \lt\ (n+1)!$$

$$2^n * 2  \lt\ n! \lt\ (n+1)!$$
Hence:
$$2^{n+1} \lt\ (n+1)!$$

I would like to know if there is something wrong with this proof. Remember, I assumed the expression is true for $n=5$, not $n=4$ (which is true too).

**Update 2:** I think is neccessary to prove the expression below by induction first:

"For $n= 5$, the expression $2^n \lt\ \frac{n!}{2}$ is true too."

We don't know if it's true for  $ n\gt\ 5$

Comment: Where did you use induction? Try something more like the following: $$2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n<2\cdot n!<(n+1)\cdot n!=(n+1)!.$$

Comment: To use induction you should be careful in choosing a base case.  Certainly $2^1 \not \lt 1!$.

Comment: Please, read the update. Thanks.

Comment: @Carlitos_30 The other answers are perfectly fine, and you should find them helpful, but I tried to address your question concerning *your* proof. My main issue concerning *your* proof is that it is completely unclear what you are assuming and where you are using your assumption. Where *exactly* do you use the inductive hypothesis? Where *exactly* do you make the condition that $n\geq5$ turn into a useful fact? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking specifically for whether or not *your* proof is correct, I have to say...if I were the one grading your work, then I would probably give it 5/10 or 6/10. Why? Well, it seems you are missing the main point concerning proofs by induction. That is, you need to

1. Prove that your result is true for some specific number $n=\,?$ (this is the **base case**).
2. Fix some $k\geq\,?$ and assume (this assumption is the inductive hypothesis) that your statement holds for $k$. Then you show that, based on your assumption, your statement is also true for $k+1$.

You really should read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof) in the future on how to write up clear induction proofs. To that end, consider the following, which is the *core* part of the inductive argument.

---

\begin{align}
2^{k+1}&= 2\cdot2^k\tag{exponent rule}\\[1em]
&< 2\cdot(k!)\tag{by inductive hypothesis}\\[1em]
&< (k+1)\cdot k!\tag{$k\geq4\implies2<k+1$}\\[1em]
&= (k+1)!\tag{factorial definition}
\end{align}
All of the other "stuff" you can write out in that template I linked to, but the above part is the main argument.

Comment: Thanks for your time. About my proof, the whole question can be reduced to this: The expression is true for n = 5. Now, we suppose that $2^k \lt\ k!$ is true for some k (which obvoiusly has to be greater or equal than 5). From $2^k \lt\ k!$ we can deduce that $2^k \lt\ \frac{k!}{2}$, being assumed that the least $k$ value in this example is 5. This is the argument I am not sure if is valid in this stage of the proof.

Comment: @Carlitos_30 Given $2^k\lt k!$, how do you _deduce_ that $2^k\lt \frac{k!}{2}$?  You can _prove_ the latter statement (independently) but you can't automatically deduce it from the former.

Comment: Because $n \ge\ 5$, it holds when $n = 5$. The third step in the proof of Daniel is justified given that $k \ge\ 4$

Answer (score 3):

For $n=4$ we have

$$2^4<4!$$

Now, assume for some $k>4$ we have $$2^k<k!$$

Then, note that

$$\begin{align}
2^{k+1}&=2\times 2^k\\\\
&<2\times k!\\\\
&<(k+1)k!\\\\
&=(k+1)!
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Can you evaluate the update, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How to structure a proof by induction:

Base case: $n=4$

$2^4 < 4!$

Inductive hypothesis: $2^n < n!$

Show that: $2^{n+1}<(n+1)!$ based on the inductive hypothesis.

$2^{n+1} = 2 \cdot 2^{n}<2\cdot 2 (n!) < (n+1)!$

For all $n\ge 4, 2^n < n!$

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: $2^n < n!$ for $n\geq 4$.

**Base case**: $2^4 < 4! \implies 16 < 24$, which is true.

**Inductive step**: Assume that $2^n < n!$ for some $n \geq 4$. Show that $2^{n+1} < (n+1)!$ as follows:

$2^n < n!$

$2^n \cdot 2 < n! \cdot 2$

and since $n! \cdot 2 < n! \cdot (n+1)$, we have

$2^n \cdot 2 < n! \cdot (n+1)$

$2^{n+1} < (n+1)!$