# Mathematical induction and sequences $1+\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{1+2+3}+\dots+\frac{1}{1+2+\dots+n}=\frac{2n}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Prove the following sequence with the help of the principle of mathematical induction

> $$1+\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{1+2+3}+\dots+\frac{1}{1+2+\dots+n}=\frac{2n}{n+1}$$

Comment: When writing with ascii, please make sure to use proper syntaxing for order of operations.  One would interpret `(1/1+2+3)` to mean $\frac{1}{1}+2+3$, not as $\frac{1}{1+2+3}$.  If you want to mean the latter, write it instead as `(1/(1+2+3))` to ensure that all of the terms are on the denominator.  Alternatively, it is preferred to type this using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and $\LaTeX$ to ensure maximum readability.

Comment: As for a hint on how to proceed, do you know the closed form for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers?  I.e. $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = 1+2+3+\dots+(n-1)+n=$?  It is a polynomial having to do with $n$, do you remember what?

Comment: No we have to prove by mathematical induction.By putting first one then k then k+1

Comment: Assuming n=k  ofcourse

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n^2+n}{2}$ so the original sum can be rewritten as:

$$1+\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{1+2+3}+\dots+\frac{1}{1+2+\dots+n}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{2}{i^2+i}$$

---

Set up the induction proof as normal.  For tips on how to format/setup an induction proof, I recommend reading [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof).  During the induction step, you should be attempting to prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{2}{i^2+i}=\frac{2(n+1)}{(n+1)+1}$ by using your induction hypothesis and algebraic manipulation.  Now, note that:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{2}{i^2+i}=\frac{2}{(n+1)^2+(n+1)}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{2}{i^2+i}$$

You may now apply your induction hypothesis.  Try then to add the two and algebraically manipulate the result to look like the intended outcome.

---

For an even more direct simplification which lends to a direct proof, one can note further that $\frac{2}{i^2+i}=\frac{2}{i}-\frac{2}{i+1}$, so the series telescopes, giving rather immediately that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{2}{i^2+i}=\frac{2}{1}-\frac{2}{n+1}$

Comment: Telescoping series is one of the prettiest things I've seen so far (which I also understand haha)