# Mathematical induction proof

Tags: induction

i need to proof the following formula by math. induction

$ \sum_{k=1}^n k!*k=(n+1)!-1  $

n ∈ N

I dont know how to start and there to end, i would appreciate any help.

Comment: This question seems to be very popular.

Comment: As for how to set up induction proofs in general, [visit this question/answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof) for a general format.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for that.

Comment: Note that $kk!=(k+1)!-k!$.  Now, evaluate the telescoping summation.

Answer (score 1):

Basis step :
$\sum_{k=1}^{1} k!*k = 1!*1 = 2!-1$

Induction step : 
$$\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^n k!*k=(n+1)!-1\\ &\implies 
 \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k!*k\\ &=  \sum_{k=1}^{n} k!*k + (n+1)!*(n+1)\\
&=(n+1)!-1 +(n+1)!*(n+1)\\
&=(n+1)!(n+1+1) -1\\
&=(n+2)! -1
\end{align}$$