# Show by induction that 2^n > n for all integers n > 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

Here's my work so far:

- base case: $n=1$
  $2^1 = 2$ , $2>1$
- induction hypothesis:
  $p(k) = 2^k > k$ $\quad \forall$ $k>0$
- induction step:
  $p(k+1) = 2^k+1 > k$ $\quad \forall$ $(k+1)>0$
  $2^k+1 = 2^k\cdot 2 = 2^k + 2^k$
  $2^k + 2^k > k+1$
  $2^k + 2$
  $2^k + 2 > k+1$

Comment: Recommend reading http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof on how to write a clear proof by induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what your induction step should look like. 
$$2^{k+1}=2\cdot 2^k>2\cdot k=k+k\geq k+1$$
The first inequality comes from the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $2^k > k$. In other words, the upper bound for $k$ is $2^k$. If the induction is true, then:
$$2^{k + 1} > k + 1$$
$$2*2^k > k + 1$$
Let's assume the worst. What if $k$ is at its upper bound? The following must still hold:
$$2*2^k > 2^k + 1$$
$$2^k > 1$$
$$k > 0$$
Since this is true for all cases, this proves the induction for all positive integers.