# Induction with inequalities

Tags: induction

Im and quite new to induction and I don't know how use induction to prove inequalities such as $4^n>n^2$ and $2^n>n$ both for $n≥1$.

For $2^n>n$ first I proved a base case 2>1. Then I substituted n for k then tried $k+1$. $2 \cdot 2^k>2k>k+1$ but now I clueless as to what to do to finish the proof.

May someone please outline steps for how to use induction to prove an inequality. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show by induction that 2^n > n for all integers n > 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012720/show-by-induction-that-2n-n-for-all-integers-n-0) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%242%5En%5Cgt%20n%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainduction&p=1). This is for the specific inequality you tried to answer, but your question also seems to be asking about how to, in general, use induction to prove inequalities. However, I believe that's something which is too general to be able to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Induction has 3 steps to follow:

- You prove that something is true for the base
- Then assume it's true for $n=m$
- Show that it is also true for $n=m+1$.

Proving the third point should do it, as you have. You just have to present it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $2^n>n$ for $n>0$.

Base case ($n=1$):

$$2^1>1$$
which is correct

Induction step (for $n$):
$$2^n>n$$

Proof (for $n+1$):
$$2^{n+1}>n+1$$
$$2^{n+1}-n>1$$

Now we use the step
$2^n>n$

So

$$2^{n+1}-n>2^{n+1}-2^n>1$$
$$2^{n+1}-2^n>1$$
$$2^n(2-1)>1$$
$$2^n>1$$

And that's true for every $n>0$