# Finding right value for formula and proving it

Tags: induction

I need to find the p value for which every n:
$n \ge p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I am given:

$n! \ge 2^n$

I'm really not sure how to approach this question. Say my base proof is $p=4$ so $n \ge 4$ and then I tried:

$(n+1)! \ge 2^n \times 2^1$ (what was originally $2^{n+1}$)

$n! \times (n+1) \gt 2^n \times 2^1$

But this is where I get stuck..
By the way, is there any other way to find $p$ other than just trying numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does $n!\ge 2^n$ come from?

Comment: @Shuri2060 I believe it's the problem statement ("Find $p$ for which, $\forall n \geq p$, $n! \geq 2^n$").

Comment: If $n!\geq2^n$ and $n\geq4$ then $(n+1)!=n!\times(n+1)\geq2^n\times4>2^n\times2^1=2^{n+1}$.

Comment: See answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof) about how to write a clear induction proof.  Do not fall into the (*very bad*) habit of starting with what you *hope* is true and then making simplifications to reach a tautology.  Instead, start with what you *know* is true and use that to prove what you hope is true.

Comment: @platty is correct. Thanks everyone . I will try to write clear induction next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $p=4$, then you have $p!=24>16=2^p$, so you only need to prove that for $n\geq 4$, you have $n!\geq 2^n$.

So, you already have step 1 of the induction proof, so let's suppose that you have for $k\geq 4$ that

$$k!\geq2^k.$$

Then

$$(k+1)!=k!(k+1)\geq2^k(k+1)\geq2^k(4+1)\geq2^k2=2^{k+1}.$$

Comment: Thats what I don't understand. How did you get to $2^k$ *(k+1) , Isn't it supped to be 2^(k+1) ?

Comment: You use the induction step, because you know that $k!\geq 2^k$.

Answer (score 1):

$$p=1,  1!=1 <2^1$$

$$p=2,  2!=2 <2^2$$

$$p=3,  3!=6 <2^3$$

$$p=4,  4!=24>2^4$$

So, for $n\ge 4$ we can prove using induction that $n!\ge 2^n $.

$$(n+1)!=n! (n+1)\ge 2^n (n+1) $$
but $$n\ge 4\implies (n+1)\ge 2$$
thus
$$(n+1)!\ge 2^n.2=2^{n+1} $$

Done!.