# proving Fibonacci sequence for all $ n > 0, F(n) < 2^n$

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

My base step:
$ S(1)=F(1)< 2^1 $

Induction hypothesis: $S(k)=F(k)< 2^k$  for all $k>0$

Induction: $ S(k+1)=F(k+1)< 2^{(k+1)}$  for all $k>0$

So would this be a valid next step to prove that hypothesis holds? - $ S(k+1)=2^k  + F(k+1)< 2^{(k+1)} $ for all $  k>0 $

Would that be correct?

Comment: [How to write a clear induction proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof).

Comment: In particular, note the difference between the phrases "for all $k>0$" and "for *some* $k>0$"

Comment: An alternative proof is as follows.  Since $F_{n+2}$ is the number of binary strings (i.e., string formed by $0$ and $1$) of length $n$ such that there are no consecutive occurrences of $1$, it follows that $F_{n+2}$ is less than or equal to $2^n$.  Thus, $$F_n=F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}<F_{n+2}\leq 2^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

No, it is wrong. You stated that the hypothesis is $F(k)<2^k$ for all $k>0$. That is, you are assuming as a hypothesis the very thing that you want to prove.

Comment: Would it then be correct to say for induction hypothesis that theorem is true for all values of k > 0?

Comment: @Mayer The inductive hypothesis is that it holds for $k$, and the inductive step is proving that, if it holds at $k$, it holds at $k+1$.

Comment: @Mayer No! It's the same problem. The induction hypothesis should be just: let $k\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that $F(k)<2^k$. Without a “for all”.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks guys!