# Tips for Mathematical induction, im student

Tags: induction

As much as I try not to do even the most basic demonstration by induction, do you know any way in which I can better understand how to do it, some steps or rules that help me guide me to do them?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof

Comment: see also here http://www.math-only-math.com/problems-on-principle-of-mathematical-induction.html