# induction to m | $n,m \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: induction

$ n,m \in \mathbb{N} $. proof with induction to $m$:

$$\binom{n}{n} + \binom{n+1}{n} + \binom{n+2}{n} + ... + \binom{n+m}{n} = \binom{n+m+1}{n+1}$$

Try to use: for $k < n$ its $$\binom{n+1}{k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k} + \binom{n}{k}$$

Now i have to do the Start of Induction and set for $m$ = 1 because i have to do it to $m$ if im not wrong.

$$\binom{n}{n} + \binom{n+1}{n} = \binom{n+1+1}{n+1}$$

so now in short its:(i think)

$$\binom{n}{n} + \binom{n+1}{n} = \binom{n+2}{n+1}$$

and if i use the rules down i get:

$$1 + \binom{n+1}{n} = \binom{n+2}{n+1}$$

the 1 is because $$\binom{n}{n} = 1$$

but now i dont know how can i go on i hope someone can help.

down below some more Rules:

$ \binom{n}{0}=1 \quad \binom{0}{0}=1 \quad \binom{n}{1}=n \quad \binom{n}{n-1}=n \quad \binom{n}{n-1}=n$

$ \binom{n}{k}= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \quad \binom{n}{k}= \binom{n}{n-k} \quad \binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \quad \binom{n}{3}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} $

Sorry for my bad english. i try to formulate all understandable.

Comment: As for how to do the induction properly, some of the linked answers in the question I linked to do it fine.  If you opt not to look at it, you will need to technically run nested-induction or double-induction.  As to how to continue with what you've done, you did your base case, but you have yet to begin your *induction step itself!*  Remembering your pascal's identity you mentioned in your second line should have things fall into place quite nicely.

Comment: In the event that it is the formulation of a coherent induction proof which is giving you trouble and not the specifics of this problem and how to apply pascal's identity, [see this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof).