# Applying the principle of mathematical Induction, prove that

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Applying the principle of mathematical Induction, prove that 
$n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is divisible by $6$ for all $n\in N$

My Attempt 
Let 
$$P(n)=n(n+1)(2n+1)$$
When $n=1$, then 
$$P(1)=6$$
Which is divisible by $6$. Hence $P(1)$ is true. 
Suppose $P(k)$ is true for some $K\in N$
$$P(k)=k(k+1)(2k+1)$$
We have to prove that $P(k+1)$ is true whenever $P(k)$ is true. Thus,
$$P(k+1)=(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)$$
$$=(k+1)(k+2)(2k+1+2)$$

How do I complete the proof?

Comment: Rewriting for convenience, $n(n+1)(2n+1)=2n^3+3n^2+n$.  Now, note that $(k+1)(k+2)(2k+1+2)=2k^3+9k^2+13k+6=\underbrace{2k^3+3k^2+k}+\underbrace{6k^2+12k+6}$

Comment: Recommended reading: [Proof writing: how to write a clear induction proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up is everything with these proofs!

In particular, you need to clearly define your terms, and you don't do that:

When you write:

> $$P(n) = n(n+1)(2n+1)$$

you define $P(n)$ as a **number**

But when you say

> Suppose $P(k)$ is true for some $k$ ...

you treat $P(k)$ as a **claim**.

I recommend that you define $P(n)$ as the claim that the number $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is divisible by $6$.

So, when you say that 'Suppose $P(k)$ is true for some $k$', you thereby assume the claim that $k(k+1)(2k+1)$ is divisible by $6$, i.e. that $k(k+1)(2k+1)=6m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: the first one is base step and $P(k)$ is for inductive hypothesis.

Comment: @blue_eyed_... But what *is* $P(k)$? Is it a number or a claim?

Comment: that's a claim.

Comment: @blue_eyed_... then what is meant by "$P(k)\color{red}{=}k(k+1)(2k+1)$"?  If $P(k)$ is a claim and not a number, you have a claim on the left hand of the "equals sign" and a number on the right hand of the "equals" sign

Comment: @blue_eyed_... OK, good. So, you should start with $k(k+1)(2k+1)=6m$, rather than with $P(k)=k(k+1)(2k+1)$

Answer (score 1):

You may complete the proof by a simple *factorisation* of $P(k+1)-P(k)$ to prove the difference is divisible by $6$.

Indeed, we have
\begin{align}
P(k+1)-P(k)&=(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)-k(k+1)(2k+1) \\
&=(k+1)\bigl((k+2)(2k+1+2)-k(2k+1)\bigr)\\
&=(k+1)\bigl((k+2-k)(2k+1)+2(k+2)\bigr) \\
&=(k+1)\bigl(2(2k+1)+2(k+2)\bigr)
=(k+1)(6k+6)=\color{red}{6(k+1)^2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Your base case looks good. Now, assume true for $n=k$.

$$k(k+1)(2k+1)=6m\to2k^3+3k^2+k=6m$$

Then show for $n=k+1$,

$$(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)=2k^3+9k^2+13k^2+6$$

Thus $$P(k+1)-P(k)=6k^2+12k+6=6(k+1)^2$$

Since we assumed $P(k)=6m$, we now see that:
$$P(k+1)=6(m+(k+1)^2)$$
and therefore true. Then write your conclusion step.

Comment: If you need help with the conclusion step - just ask!