# Prove that, for every natural number $n$, $10^n > n^2$

Tags: induction

I attempted to solve the proof but looking at another proof but I got stuck. Here's what I have so far.

Let $n = 1$, $10 > 1$. 
Assume valid for $k$ greater than or equal to $1$. 
Then $n = k + 1$.

$10^k > k^2$ .... Case(1) = $100 > 10$

And then what is after? Am I even doing the proof properly? I feel that I did a step incorrectly which led me to a dead-end.

EDIT: There was a hint in the back of my book, "$10n^2 = n^2 + 2n^2 + 7n^2$, now prove that $2n^2 \geq 2n$ and $7n^2 \geq 1$.

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to write a clear induction proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof)

Answer (score 1):

You have the right general concept, but you should be much clearer about your strategy.  You want to show that *if* the statement holds for some $k \geq 1$, then it also holds for $k+1$.  So assume that $10^k > k^2$ for *some* $k \geq 1$.  Then, $10^{k+1} = 10^k \cdot 10 > 10k^2$.  All you have left to do is check that $10k^2 > (k+1)^2$ for $k \geq 1$, and I'll leave this part to you.

Comment: I see now! This was my first attempt at proof by induction and my question goes to show my lack of intuition. Thank you for the help JavaMan.