# Prove by mathematical induction that $\sum_{i=0}^n (2i-1)^2 = \frac{n(2n+1)(2n-1)}{3}$

Tags: induction

One of my homework problems is to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2 = \frac{n(2n+1)(2n-1)}{3}$

I already completed the basis step

$[2(1)-1]^2 = 1 $

$\frac{(1)[2(1)+1][2(1)-1]}{3} = 1$

Then I assumed that the proposition was true for n=k+1 which leaves me with
$\frac{k(2k+1)(2k-1)}{3}$ + $[2(k+1)-1]^2$ = $\frac{k[2(k+1)+1][2(k+1)-1]}{3}$

However, I am stuck here, as the term $[2(k+1)-1]^2$ produces a constant term and $\frac{k[2(k+1)+1][2(k+1)-1]}{3}$ (when the numerator is multiplied out) has no constants. Any ideas, guys?

---

Edits:
After reading some of the comments I found my original mistake. I should have written $\frac{(k+1)[2(k+1)+1][2(k+1)-1]}{3}$ instead of $\frac{k[2(k+1)+1][2(k+1)-1]}{3}$.

This leaves me with $\frac{k(2k+1)(2k-1)}{3}$ + $[2(k+1)-1]^2$ = $\frac{(k+1)[2(k+1)+1][2(k+1)-1]}{3}$

However, I am still lost on what to do next. I'm not having any luck combining these fractions, anyone got good ideas?

Comment: Are you certain that the sum starts at $i = 0$ and not $i = 1$?

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to write a clear induction proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you must prove is that
$$\frac{k(2k+1)(2k-1)}3+[2(k+1)-1]^2=\frac{\color{red}{(k+1)}[2(k+1)+1][2(k+1)-1]}3$$

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I'm still having some trouble though, I edited the question to reflect where I am at in solving the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to prove is $$\frac{k(2k+1)(2k-1)}{3}+(2k+1)^2=\frac{(k+1)(2k+3)(2k+1)}{3}$$
The left-hand side is $$\frac{k(2k+1)(2k-1)+3(2k+1)^2}{3}=\frac{(2k+1)(2k+3)(k+1)}{3}$$
$$(2k+1)(2k^2-k+6k+3)$$ and $$(2k+3)(k+1)=2k^2-k+6k+3$$

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I still have no idea how to reach the right hand side of this equation from the left side though, I've tried combining the fractions but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n(2i-1)^2=\frac{n(2n+1)(2n-1)}{3}$. Then $S_1=\sum_{i=0}^1(2i-1)^2=2$. But on the other hand, $S_1=\frac{1\cdot(2+1)(2-1)}{3}=1$. Contradiction !

I guess there may be some error in your question.

Comment: I started the summation at i=0 instead of i=1 by mistake. Thanks though!