# Proof by induction summation

Tags: summation, induction, geometric-progressions

I'm a little bit lost. I'm learning Math Discrete, and right now I'm in Proof by Induction. I have a question that uses a summation, and I never saw this kind of question before. Can someone help me? :(

Tese:
I dont know :(

$$2\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{3^j} = 1- \left(\frac13\right)^n$$

$$2\cdot \frac13 + 2\cdot\frac{1}{3^2} + 2\cdot\frac1{3^3} + \dots + 2\cdot\frac{1}{3^n} = 1 - \left(\frac13\right)^n$$

Base ($n=1$):

\begin{align*}
2\cdot\frac1{3^1}&=1-\left(\frac13\right)^1\\
2\cdot\frac13 &= 1-\frac13\\
\frac23 &= 1-\frac13\\
\frac23 &= \frac23
\end{align*}

Comment: General structure of induction proof : *step 1* prove that the equality holds for $n=1$. *Step 2* prove that, assuming that the equality holds for $n$, prove that it holds also for $n+1$.

Comment: Using * for both multiplication and exponentiation is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Obligatory suggested reading:  [How to write a clear induction proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof).  Also, [MathJax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can type with $\LaTeX$ and MathJax here rather than relying on ascii.

Comment: In order to help you get started with MathJax, I have retyped the part you have posted in ascii at the end of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations on proving the initial $n=1$ case. The next step is to prove the *induction* step. That is, assuming the equality holds for $n$, prove that it holds for $n+1$. The reason this works is you have a base $n=1$ case you know to be true through other means, so if it's true for $n=1$ and you prove given $n=1$ that $(n=1)+1=2$ is true, you can reach $n=$ any number you like.

In general with induction with summations, try to remove the summation component(s). Those are the hardest to manipulate.

**Given:**
$$2 \sum_{j=1}^{n} {1 \over 3^j} = 1-\left(1 \over 3 \right)^n$$
**Check**
$$2 \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} {1 \over 3^j} = 1-\left(1 \over 3 \right)^{n+1}$$
Since you know that: $\sum_{i=1}^{m+1} f(i)= \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(i) + f(m+1)$, I would try that first. Also expand the right-hand side
$$2 \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} {1 \over 3^j} = 2 \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} {1 \over 3^j} + {1 \over 3^{n+1}}\right) = 2 \sum_{j=1}^{n} {1 \over 3^j} + {2 \over 3^{n+1}}$$
$$1-\left(1 \over 3 \right)^{n+1} = 1- \left({1 \over 3}\right)^n \times {1 \over 3}$$
Notice what you have now. The two halves of the equality that were given!
$$\mathbf{2 \sum_{j=1}^{n} {1 \over 3^j}} + {2 \over 3^{n+1}} = \mathbf{1- \left({1 \over 3}\right)^n} \times {1 \over 3}$$
Substitute the left-hand side:
$$1-\left(1 \over 3^n \right) + {2 \over 3^{n+1}} = 1- \left({1 \over 3^n}\right) \times {1 \over 3}$$
Let's put it over a common $3^{n+1}$ denominator:
$$3^{n+1}-\left(3^{n+1} \over 3^n \right) + {2*3^{n+1} \over 3^{n+1}} = 3^{n+1}- \left({3^{n+1} \over 3^n}\right) \times {1 \over 3}$$
Simplify:
$$3^{n+1}-3 + 2 = 3^{n+1}- 3 \times {1 \over 3}$$
Arithmetic:
$$3^{n+1}-1 = 3^{n+1}-1$$
The above statement is true $\forall n$, so we have proven the induction step.