# Combinatorial proof of $2 \cdot 3^0 + 2 \cdot 3^1 + 2 \cdot 3^2 + \cdots 2 \cdot 3^{n-1} = 3^n-1$

Tags: combinatorial-proofs

I'm having trouble combinatorially proving: $$2 \cdot 3^0 + 2 \cdot 3^1 + 2 \cdot 3^2 + \cdots 2 \cdot 3^{n-1} = 3^n-1$$

I understand that the right hand side can be expressed as the number of possible n-length strings from an alphabet {a,b,c}, minus some specific string, such as "abc".

I see also that the left hand side is a finite geometric series where a = 2 and r = 3 and that I can algebraically prove its sum to be $3^n - 1$.

But how can I prove this combinatorially? How can I show the geometric series to be an answer to the same n-length string problem as the right side, if that is the correct interpretation for the proof?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  As I commented to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557486/verification-of-proof-by-induction), $ 2+6+18+⋯+2⋅3n−1=(3−1)+(3−1)⋅3+(3−1)⋅3^2+⋯+(3−1)⋅3^{n−1} $ telescopes to $3⋅3^n−1−1=3^n−1$

Comment: OP specifically wants a combinatorial interpretation of the left hand side

Comment: Note that $3^n-1$ is the number of all ternary strings (strings made from symbols $0$, $1$, and $2$) of length $n$ that is not $000\ldots0$.  The number of such strings such that $k$ is the last (rightmost) non-zero location is given by $2\cdot 3^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3^n-1$ is the number of strings of length $n$ with characters $\{a,b,c\}$ that isn't $\underbrace{aa\ldots a}_n$.

If the first character is $b,c$, the remainder of the characters can be whatever, so there are $2\cdot3^{n-1}$ strings of this form.

If the first character is $a$, then the number of strings of length $n$ with characters from $\{a,b,c\}$ not including $\underbrace{aa\ldots a}_n$ is the same as the number of strings of length $n-1$ with the same properties, of which there are $3^{n-1}-1$.

So, combinatorially, you can see that $3^n-1=2\cdot3^{n-1}+3^{n-1}-1$, which is the desired relation.