# Need help proving $1+3+\cdots+(2n-1)+(2n+1)+(2n-1)+\cdots+3+1=n^2+(n+1)^2$

Tags: induction

I am having trouble in identifying how $n=k+1$ differs from $n=k$.

Assume it is true for some integer $k \ge 1$, that is
$1+3+(2k-1)+(2k+1)+(2k-1)+3+1$. I need help getting to how $n=k$ implies $n=k+1$ in this case.

Comment: Suggested reading: [How To Write a Clear Induction Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof).

Comment: $\color{blue}1+\color{brown}3+\cdots+\color{green}{(2n-1)}+(2n+1)+\color{blue}{(2n-1)}+\color{brown}{(2n-3)}+\cdots+\color{green}1  $ $=\color{blue}{1+(2n-1)}+\color{green}{3+(2n-3)}+...+\color{brown}{(2n-1)+1}+(2n+1)$ $=2n\times n+(2n+1)=n^2+(n+1)^2$

Comment: Prove $1 + 3 + ...... (2n-1)= n^2$ first.  Then that wil mean $1 + 3 + ...... +(2n-1) + (2n+1)$ because $2n+1 = 2(n+1) -1$.  Then  $(2n-1) + .... + 3 + 1 = n^2$ and we are done.... $1 + 3 + ...... +(2n-1) + (2n+1) + (2n-1) + .... + 3 + 1=(n+1)^2 +n^2$

Answer (score 1):

So, finish your base case and set up your induction hypothesis.

We suppose that it is true for some integer $k\geq 1$ that we have $1+3+\color{red}{\dots}+(2k-1)+(2k+1)+(2k-1)+\color{red}{\dots}+3+1=k^2+(k+1)^2$

(*you forgot your dots there...*)

We try to use this hypothesis to prove the case for when $n=k+1$.  Now, it follows that:

$$\begin{array}{l}1+3+\dots+(2k-1)+(2k+1)+\color{blue}{(2k+3)+(2k+1)}+(2k-1)+\dots+3+1\\=\dots\\=\dots~~\text{by induction hypothesis}\\=\dots\\\vdots\\=(k+1)^2+(k+2)^2\end{array}$$

Note that anywhere where $k$ appeared previously, $k+1$ now appears.  I went ahead and simplified some of those... but where we had $k^2$ we now have $(k+1)^2$.  Where we had $(k+1)^2$ we now have $((k+1)+1)^2$ or in other words $(k+2)^2$.  Where the largest term in the middle of the summation was previously $(2k+1)$ the largest term in the middle of the summation was now $(2(k+1)+1)$ or simplified $(2k+3)$.

Now... as for a hint on actually applying your induction hypothesis, maybe take the middle terms that I colored blue and add it later.  If you were to add only the black terms in the above, the induction hypothesis tells you how you can simplify that.

Comment: Thanks, I have the base case on my paper, I just didn't write it out.

Comment: I definitely got it now. I totally forgot to substitute the induction hypothesis in for $n=k$. Very simple after realizing that, so thanks for the help. My brain is fried from studying for finals.

Answer (score 0):

From here
$$1 + 3 + \ldots + (2k - 1) + (2k + 1) + (2k - 1) + \ldots + 3 + 1$$
to here
$$1 + 3 + \ldots + (2k - 1) + (2k + 1) + \underbrace{(2k + 3) + (2k + 1)}_\text{These are new} + (2k - 1) + \ldots + 3 + 1.$$
Let me know if you need more help.