# Prove by induction $1+2+2^{2}+...+2^{n-1} =2^{n}-1; \forall n \geqslant 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction

How can I prove by induction the following statement:

$1+2+2^{2}+...+2^{n-1} =2^{n}-1; \forall n \geqslant 1$

Comment: It's a geometric series

Comment: $ \frac{1-2^n}{1-2}=2^n-1 $

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to write a clear induction proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof)