# Struggling with questions about discrete math Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove my induction that "" n^2 + 7n + 3 ≤ 3 n^2 for n ≥ 4 ""

I know that the base case is n=4 and I assume that n= k is true and I have to prove that it is also true for n= k+1

but I don't know how to go about starting that from what I have

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to write a clear induction proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof).

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that: $$2n^2-7n-3\geq0$$

For $n=4$ we obtain $1\geq0$, which is true.

Now, by assumption of the induction for $n\geq4$  we obtain:
$$2(n+1)^2-7(n+1)-3=2n^2-3n-8=2n^2-7n-3+4n-5>0.$$

Thus, by the axioma of an induction we are done.

Comment: The final inequality could use a bit more detail.  $\underbrace{(2n^2-7n-3)}_{\geq 0~\text{by I.H.}} + \underbrace{(4n-5)}_{\geq 16-5~\text{since }n\geq 4}>0$

Comment: @JMoravitz  Thank you for your interest!

Comment: thanks for the response

Comment: @Minusa  You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $2n^2\geq 7n+3$ for $n\geq 4$.

**Induction start**

For $n=4$ we have $2n^2=32\geq31=7n+3$

For $n=5$, $2n^2=50\geq 38=7n+3$

**Induction hypothesis**

Assume it holds for $n=k$ ($\geq 4$).

**Induction step**

$$2(k+1)^2=2(k^2+2k+1)$$
$$=2k^2+4k+2\geq7k+3+4k+2 \geq 7k+5+4\cdot4$$
$$>7k+10=7(k+1)+3$$

Thus $2(k+1)^2\geq7(k+1)+3$ as required.

Comment: thank you for response