# mathematical induction question: 1x1! + 2x2! + ... + nxn! = (n+1)!-1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I know the solution to this question:

test basis step: 
p(1)= 1x1!=(1+1)!-1 
1x1 = (2)!-1 
1 = 2-1, true

assume n=k 
p(k) = 1x1! + 2x2! + ... + kxk! = (k+1)!-1

proof that if p(k) then p(k+1) 
p(k+1) = 1x1! + 2x2! + ... + kxk! + (k+1)x(K+1)! = [(k+1)+1]!-1

here is where I get lost how did we get from: 
p(k+1) = (k+1)!-1 + (k+1)x(k+1)! = (k+2)!-1 
to 
p(k+1) = (k+1)! x (1+k+1)-1 = (k+2)!-1

Comment: What is your doubt?

Comment: Please please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: As to your specific question... "*how did we get from...*"  Recall that $\color{red}{b} + a\color{red}{b} = 1\cdot \color{red}{b} + a\cdot \color{red}{b} = (1+a)\cdot \color{red}{b}$.  Also, recall that $(a+1)\cdot a! = (a+1)!$.  Here... $\color{red}{(k+1)!}+(k+1)\color{red}{(k+1)!} = (1+(k+1))\color{red}{(k+1)!} = (k+2)\cdot (k+1)! = (k+2)!$

Comment: Also, highly recommended reading: [How to write a clear induction proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof)  You should not be writing what you hope to be true and through manipulation attempt to arrive at a tautology... you should be starting with only one side and through a chain of equalities reach the desired second side.

Comment: Dear JMoravitz, thank you very much for the clear expalnation, kind regards Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(k+1)=(k+1)!-1 + (k+1)\cdot (k+1)!$$
$$=(k+1)!\left[1+k+1\right] - 1$$
$$=(k+1)!\left(k+2\right) - 1$$
$$=(1\cdot2\cdot3.....(k+1)(k+2))-1$$
$$=(k+2)!-1$$

Comment: Do not answer questions that are duplicate. If you have a proof that is different from those givin in the earlier question, post it here.

Comment: Ah, answered it before the duplicate tag was placed, my bad!!

Comment: Dear Smitri Sivakumar, thank you for the clear and detailed answer Edward