# Proving a statement using mathematical induction?

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

[image]
For this one, the idea is to assume that it is first true for $$n=3$$ and then get $$4^3 = \frac{4(4^{n} - 16)}{3}$$ and then assume that it is true for $$n=k$$, where k is a natural number, whereby we get $$4^k = \frac{4(4^{k} - 16)}{3}$$, and then for $$n = k+1$$ and then get $$4^{k+1} = \frac{4(4^{k+1}-16)}{3}$$. Then we get $$4^{k+1}=4^{k}\times 4$$ which therefore becomes $$4\left( \frac{4\left( 4^{k}-16\right) }{3 } \right) =4\times 4^{k}$$.

Is this good?

Comment: It might help if you stated what you were trying to prove. $4^k = \frac{4(4^{k} - 16)}{3}$ is not correct

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When attempting to prove something in induction... when building your induction step you should start with the LHS, then through a chain of equalities (*in the middle of which one of the equalities will depend on the induction hypothesis*) eventually show it reaches the RHS of what you wanted.  Do *not* start with what you hope to be true as your first step.  Read more on how to properly format such a proof [Proof writing: how to write a clear induction proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof)

Comment: In any event, you have not in your attempt successfully shown that the LHS of what you want is actually equal to the RHS of what you want... and you will not be able to if we are correct in what it is you are attempting to do.  It may have been true that $4^3$ happens to equal $\frac{4\cdot (4^3-16)}{3}$ but it is blatantly false that $4^4=256$ would be equal to $\frac{4\cdot(4^4-16)}{3}=320$.  *Perhaps* you might be trying to prove something else?  Maybe something without an equals sign but instead an inequality?

Comment: Now that you have included an image... we see that you are asking about a *summation*.  Where in your attempt have you shown anything involving a summation?  You talk about "*it being true for $k$*"... the LHS should have been $(4^3+4^4+4^5+\dots+4^k)$ including everything from the first term and onwards, not just the final term.

Comment: @JMoravitz So the ellipis will be included when youo're proving for n = 3, n = k, and n = k+1?

Comment: Yes... of course.  The statement is that $4^3 = \dfrac{4(4^3-16)}{3}$, that $4^3+4^4 = \dfrac{4(4^4-16)}{3}$, that $4^3+4^4+4^5 = \dfrac{4(4^5-16)}{3}$, that $4^3+4^4+4^5+4^6 = \dfrac{4(4^6-16)}{3}$ and so on... that the **sum of all terms** from $4^3$ on up to $4^k$ will be $\sum\limits_{i=3}^k 4^i = \dfrac{4(4^k-16)}{3}$